# How to find all the files for a specific year and empty them through Bash Script

Tags: bash

I am facing one issue with one of my scenario.I need to find the files for a specific year i.e 2012 and empty the files.I am using the below command

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -newermt 2012-01-01 ! -newermt 2013-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

works perfectly but

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -newermt 2016-01-01 ! -newermt 2017-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
echo "Cleaning Complete ...."
```

gives the  the below error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Is there something wrong in the syntax or the combination of command i am using.

Comment: The line from above works perfectly fine for me using `bash`.

Comment: Just a hint: do you really have a whitespace between `{}` and `\;` ?

Comment: Yes came to know one more thing.if there is another command after the above command it throws the above error.What i meant to say is    `echo " Cleaning"
find . -type f -newermt 2016-01-01 ! -newermt 2017-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;`        works but `echo "cleaning"
find . -type f -newermt 2016-01-01 ! -newermt 2017-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
echo "Hello cleaned"`       gives the above error. Any idea why this strange thing is happening if i put a simple echo after the command.

Comment: This should work - unless you have the `echo "hello cleaned"` in the same line without another semicolon between the two commands (`find ...` and `echo ...`). The first (escaped) semicolon does not terminate the `find` shell command.

Comment: @radix edited the question for better understandably .

Comment: Hm...do you still get the error if you add a second semicolon at the end of the line with `find`?

Answer (score 3):

Was able to resolve the issue by the below command.

```
find . -type f -newermt 2016-01-01 ! -newermt 2017-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; && echo "Cleaning Complete ...."
```